# ReactJS onclick of a button display mongo collection in table format

Tags: reactjs, render, react-component

Hi I'm new to React and building few things in React and this may seem a very generic question.

I want to show a table on click of button. Below is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } 
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import Panel from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Panel';
import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Col';
import ButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/lib/ButtonGroup';
import FormGroup from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormGroup';



this.state = {
    showSubmit: false,
};

submitForm = () => {
    window.alert('test');
} 

toggleSubmitForm = () => {
    this.setState({
        showSubmit: !this.state.showSubmit
    });
    window.alert('test2');
}

export default (props) => {

  return (
    <AppLayout title="Table Con" activeModules={props.activeModules}>
      <Protected>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <h4>
            Welcome to the page
            !
            </h4>
        </div>
    <Button
        className="btn btn-secondary"
            bsSize="small"
            onClick={this.toggleSubmitForm}
          >
           Show Table
          </Button>

          {this.state.showSubmit && (
            <div className="container-fluid well" id="submitT">
              <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                <Grid>
                  <Row>
                    <Col xs={12}>
                      <div>
                        <h3>HERE</h3>
                      </div>s
                      <br />
                      <br />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </Grid>
                <Button type="submit" bsStyle="success" bsSize="large">
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </form>
            </div>
          )}
      </Protected>
    </AppLayout>
  );
};
```

But when onClick is called, nothing is happening.

I'm not sure where I'm failing.

Also, if i want to call a mongo collection and render the table after I click on Show Table button. What are the changes to be made ?

Comment: For some reason, you are combining functional and class component features. 
In functional components, you do not have state feature (unless you are using useState). Plus "this"  is connected to your function (since its arrow function it is not) and this.submitForm is undefined. Convert your functional component to pure or regular class component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @noitse pointed out, you are mixing statefull and stateless component features.

However, React added a new alternative if you want to keep your component as a function, Hooks. Here's what you code will look like as a hook :

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default props => {
    const[showSubmit, setShowSubmit] = useState(false)

  return (
    <AppLayout title="Table Con" activeModules={props.activeModules}>
      <Protected>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <h4>Welcome to the page !</h4>
        </div>
        <Button className="btn btn-secondary" bsSize="small" onClick={setShowSubmit(true)}>
          Show Table
        </Button>

        {showSubmit && /* Your table*/}
      </Protected>
    </AppLayout>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are combining functional and class component features.
Functional components do not have access to the state unless you are using useState feature (16.3 update). Any "this." is basically undefined in your code.
Rewrite your component like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react' // or PureComponent
// ...other imports

    class YourComponent extends Component {
        state = {
            showSubmit: false
        }

        submitForm = () => { /* what ever */}
        toggleSubmitForm  = () => { 
            this.setState({showSubmit: !this.state.showSubmit})
        }

        render(){
            return(
                ... your render code
            )
        }
    }

    export default YourComponent
```